# How to add two n-bit binary integers in Haskell?

Tags: c++, haskell

As a newbie in Haskell, I'm trying to add two n-bit binary integers.

Below is what I wrote in C++ to show what I want to implement. Can any one show me how to do it in Haskell?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> lhs{1,1,1,1}, rhs{1,0,1,1};

    //! 3 inputs -> 2 outputs
    deque<int> sum;
    int carry = 0;
    for( auto l = lhs.crbegin(), r = rhs.crbegin(); l != lhs.crend(); ++l, ++r)
    {
        int digit_sum = carry + *l + *r;
        sum.push_front(digit_sum%2);
        carry = digit_sum/2;
    }

    if(carry)
        sum.push_front(carry);

    for(auto b : sum)
        cout << b << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
1 1 0 1 0
```

Below is where I stuck in Haskell..

```
add :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
add (l,r,c) = (((l+r+c) `mod` 2), ((l+r+c) `div` 2))

bAdd :: [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int], Int)
bAdd []     []       =  ([fst (add (0,0,0))], snd (add(0,0,0)))
bAdd [l]    [r]      =  ([fst (add (l,r,0))], snd (add(l,r,0)))
bAdd (l:lt) (r:rt)   =  ([fst (add (l,r,add (head)))])
```

Comment: @EdChum Ok I've added what I did in Haskell..

Comment: What do you need this for? The built-in `Integer` type represents arbitrary-precision binary integers.

Comment: @dfeuer It's an exercise from CLRS. I did it to learn Haskell. Nothing serious.

Comment: You will not learn much or quickly by having other people do exercises for you.

Comment: @dfeuer I've been working on this problem for more than 6 hours. I believe the best thing I can do now is to have a look at the correct answer. Or come back to it one or two months later.How much do you think I can learn from this exercise if I pay another 6 hours on it? Do you really believe it's worthwhile? Please be an adult.Please believe that a 34-year old guy is able to make the right decision for himself.

Comment: @YueWang, I'm a 34 year old as well. I've been working on a problem for nearly a month. I had a new insight the other day, and now I think I'll likely have a solution within a few days, although of course I could be wrong. Take a walk, get some pizza, and try again. Or get a hint, instead of a full solution, and try to learn from that. Just my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add one bit first.

```hs
addWithCarry :: Bool -> Bool -> (Bool, Bool)
addWithCarry x y = (x /= y, x && y)
--                  "x+y"   its carry
```

Then, let's move to lists:

```hs
-- numbers are represented LSB first e.g. 6 is [False,True,True]
addBitsWithCarry :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> Bool -> [Bool]
-- when we ran out of digits on both args:
addBitsWithCarry []     []     False = []
addBitsWithCarry []     []     True  = [True]
-- when we ran out of digits on one arg, add a zero there:
addBitsWithCarry a      []     c     = addBitsWithCarry a       [False] c
addBitsWithCarry []     b      c     = addBitsWithCarry [False] b       c
-- some digits on both sides
addBitsWithCarry (x:xs) (y:ys) c     = ???
          where (z,c') = addWithCarry ???
```

Can you figure out what to do in the last lines?

If you can assume that your numbers have the same bit length (as you do in your C++ code), you can remove the two lines above adding zeros.

---

Extra hint:

```hs
-- some digits on both sides
addBitsWithCarry (x:xs) (y:ys) c     = lsbOfTheSum : restOfTheSum
          where (z,c') = addWithCarry someBit someOtherBit someCarry
                lsbOfTheSum  = ???  -- what is the first bit (LSB) of the result?
                restOfTheSum = ???  -- how to compute the other bits (think recursively)
                someBit      = ???  -- what bit we should add at this step?
                someOtherBit = ???  -- ... with what other bit?
                someCarry    = ???  -- ... using which carry?
```

If you understand how binary sum works, and you have a basic understanding of Haskell, pattern matching, and recursion, you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Please show the full solution. I need a little bit more time to think in  FP way.

Comment: `addWithCarry` is a half-adder (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29). You will need a full adder near those `???`.

Comment: Stop doing this. It's just like teasing a little kid. I cann'tsolve it today. But pretty sure I will be able to do it months later.To be honest, this way is rather offensive.

Comment: I'm sorry but no offense was meant. Not completely disclosing an answer is a common practice on basic exercises in functional programming, so to prod the poster to think about the problem and devise his/her own solution. Indeed, completely solving an exercise which could be a homework assignment is frowned upon.

Comment: If you're doing this as an exercise, what do you gain by having a complete solution provided to you? These folks are trying to help you figure it out yourself; if this problem is still completely beyond you, put it aside for a while and work on something easier.

Comment: @amalloy As you said, this problem is completely beyond me. So my gain is **TIME**. Just like you want to enjoy a classic Chinese poem, should I teach you step by step so that you can read it on your own 5 years later? Or just give you an English translation first?